# print double with custom rounding and thousand separator

Tags: c#, formatting, double

I've a lot of number to format and I would like them to be readable easily but my users. I need to have:

- Custom rounding values (from 0 to 10)
- Thousand Separator
- Less garbage
- fast processing (update rate : ~10hz)

The best I came up with is this code:

```
private string RoundToString(double d)
{
    return Double.IsNaN(d) ? "Out Of Bounds" : d.ToString("N" + (int)numUpDownRoundValue.Value);
}
```

but I get *a lot* of useless `0` if the rounding is high:

```
182,0000000000  370,5000000000          370,5444319880  121,0000000000  517,0000000000  5 949 090,8555680300                        
105,3700000000  158,2750000000          165,4869516069  74,1850000000   245,4200000000  2 656 893,0080484100            
107 277,0000000000  109 452,0000000000          110 879,4795092180  100 261,0000000000  119 221,0000000000  1 780 170 043,5204900000
```

I also try this one:

```
private string RoundToString(double d)
{
    return Double.IsNaN(d) ? "Out Of Bounds" : Math.Round(d, (int)numUpDownRoundValue.Value).ToString("N");
}
```

But the `N` option crop to early (loss of precision)

### Edit

What I want :

```
182 370,5 -- 370,5444319880 -- 121 517 -- 5 949 090,85556803                    
105,37 -- 158,275 -- 165,4869516069 -- 74,185 -- 245,42 -- 2 656 893,00804841           
107 277 -- 109 452 -- 110 879,479509218 -- 100 261  119 221 -- 1 780 170 043,52049
```

In other words, I want thousand separator and no useless zeros.

Comment: I don't understand; you asked for 10 decimal digits and you got 10 - what's the problem?  What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *up to* 10 digits past the decimal but don't want training zeros use:

```
d.ToString("#,##0."+new string('#',(int)numUpDownRoundValue.Value))
```

Comment: Well it does the job :) Can you explain what mean `#,##0.#X` ?

Comment: Not as well as [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can, but `#` is a digit placeholder that does not print leading or trailing zeros.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
d.ToString("#,#.##########")
```

Look up [custom numeric format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the msdn site.